# AngularJS execute some action in all application instances

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have AngularJS app called myApp. It has several controllers which are used in different pages (website is based on Symfony so page reloads happens sometimes). I need to execute some lines of code in every controller. how do I do that without duplicating that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `angular.service`

### Services

*Angular services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). **You can use services to organize and share code across your app.***

click here for [More details](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)